# Why are empty measurable spaces and empty topological spaces not desirable?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, soft-question

The definition of a $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}$ on a set $X$ (or $\sigma$-ring) requires $\mathscr{F}$ to be a non-empty subset of $\mathscr{P}(X)$.  Why is this convention taken?
What is the issue with allowing for empty measurable spaces?

Similarly, why is a topology defined to be a  non-empty collection of $\mathscr{P}(X)$?  Whats the issue with allowing an "empty" **topological space**?

Comment: For the second: a topology must have empty set and $X$ as open sets (for good reasons), so the fact that it's nonempty follows from that and is not an additional requirement.

Comment: $\langle \emptyset, \emptyset \rangle$ is not a topology. $\langle \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\rangle$ is a topological space.

Comment: I know that, that is the first part of the statement of the question, the second part is what are these "good reasons"?

Comment: If $\langle \emptyset,\emptyset\rangle$ were a topology, there would be no continuous functions from it. On the other hand the empty function $e:\emptyset \to X$ is continuous from $\langle \emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\rangle$ to **any** topological space $X$. So we have an initial object in the category.

Comment: Cool, that's a pretty solid reason, thanks J.L :)

Comment: Similarly for the first.  Whether or not $X = \varnothing$, the sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ on it is not empty, since is has (at least) $\varnothing \in \mathcal F$.

Comment: Yup, thanks GEdgar :)